# is it possible to run a javascript function on a website by using the url of the website?

Tags: javascript, function, url

Suppose that we have a website called `example.com`

In this website we have a single button which when clicked runs a javascript function let's say `myFunction()`

Is it possible to create an http request from the url bar of firefox so that when this http request is finished, the button would be clicked as well?

For instance, it would be good if I could include this url to the url bar of my browser

`example.com + javascript:myFunction()`

which would run the function after loading the page without having me to click on the button

however this does not work for me.

thank you in advance

Comment: are you planning to create some bot?? :D

Comment: Im completely confused but think you may be lookign for a pageload() event

Comment: No. He wants to perform click event on some random website

Comment: Search for `greasemonkey` (for FF) or similar tools for the browser of your preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible.

You can't append JS in a url. You can however use JS *instead of* a url, so `javascript:myFunction()`

Comment: provided the page is loaded before that. ;) But then, I guess, nowadays the the console is a better place to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    myFunction();
}
```

as soon as the URL has loaded `myFunction` will execute, but unless some kind of *bad* server side logic is used, you can not tell a page to execute some arbitrary JavaScript after it has loaded without the page knowing of it.